# MySQL query set LIMIT by unique values of a field

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that looks like this

```
---------------------------------------
|id      |setId   |value1   |value2   |
---------------------------------------
|1       |1       |value1   |value2   |
|2       |2       |value1   |value2   |
|3       |2       |value1   |value2   |
|4       |3       |value1   |value2   |
---------------------------------------
```

basically there are many entries (above is just an example) with unique `IDs`, but the many have the same `"setID"`.

Now let's say I have the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE <rule> LIMIT 0,50
```

The `<rule>` isn't always the same, so might aswell ignore it here. That would return the first 50 entries.

In this case I need it to return the first `n` rows with up to 50 unique setIDs.
That means that if I we look at the above table with this custom "LIMIT" set to "2" it would return the first 3 rows. If the LIMIT would be "3" it would have to return all 4 rows (since `id` 2 and 3 share the same setID).

If I use the `GROUP BY setId` the custom LIMIT would work, but It wouldn't return the row with `id` of 3 at all for example.

What would be the best possible SQL string to achieve that? Help is much appreciated.

**edit**
the table is already ordered by `setId`, so no need to use any `ORDER BY` here.

**edit2**
as said in the comments probably the best way of doing this would be:
"One full copy of the results is joined against a second copy of the results that uses GROUP BY and JOIN to find the first 50 setIDs."

sadly I'm not that familiar with the SQL syntax, anyone knows a good way of doing this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: don't have time to write and test the whole thing, but basically you get the results you want (without LIMIT) and then JOIN with the same set of results grouped by setID, limiting that to 50. Note that choice of ORDER BY is potentially important.

Comment: The table is already ordered by setId, so that's fine. If I GROUP BY setId some rows won't get returned (like value1 and value2 of the row with id 3 wouldn't be returned.

Comment: did you understand what I am saying about the JOIN? One full copy of the results is joined against a second copy of the results that uses GROUP BY and JOIN to find the first 50 setIDs.

Comment: Note that while `LIMIT n` without `ORDER BY` *will* return `n` number of results, they will be the first `n` only by coincidence. Now, for further help with this problem, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1. (and I suggest your example seeks a subset smaller than 50)

Comment: @Strawberry It may be some one is not familiar with sqlfiddle..

Comment: @AmitGarg I suspect that many people are unfamiliar with sqlfiddle. What's your point?

Comment: @Strawberry I think shiro can give the answer if he knows or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query should do the trick:

```
select * from table t,
(select distinct tt.setId from table tt order by tt.setId limit 50) sets
 where t.setId = sets.setId 
order by t.Id
```

In the `sets` subquery we find all the `setId`'s what you need (first 50 unique ones) and then in `where` clause we tell MySQL that we want to obtain only records with these `setId`'s.

**edit** The author of the question mentioned that the

> table is already ordered by setId, so no need to use any ORDER BY here

. Tables themselves are not sorted, and if we use the query without `order by`, the order is not guaranteed. Though, it is likely that the actual order will be the order in which the rows were added, you cannot rely on this. Only `order by` construction will guarantee the order of the result set.

Comment: It seems correct answer but there may be syntax error.